# Can't use nssm set command in batch script

Tags: batch-file, nssm

When using this command in my batch script the `set` command is interpreted as the default windows batch "set an environment command":

```
@echo off
echo "Always run this script as Administrator. If you don't the service will be installed but not correctly configured!"

set serviceName=MyApp
set serviceLabel=MyApp
set serviceExe=MyApp.exe

set maindir=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\MyApp\\
set nssm=%maindir%\\lib\\nssm-2.24\\win64\\nssm.exe

%nssm% install %serviceName% "%maindir%\\%serviceExe%"
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Now that you've modified your code, did you notice that `%nssm%` has a value of `C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\MyApp\\\\lib\\nssm-2.24\\win64\\nssm.exe`? I would suggest that is your issue! _Windows uses a single back slash as it's path separator_. It also shows that you should be using either, `"%maindir%%serviceExe%"` or `maindir=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\MyApp`. Additionally, I would recommend that you use this syntax, `Set "VariableName=StringValue"`.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you.
I do realize that I should properly learn batch scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example, based upon my comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "serviceName=MyApp"
Set "serviceExe=MyApp.exe"
Set "maindir=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\MyApp"
Set "nssm=%maindir%\\lib\\nssm-2.24\\win64\\nssm.exe"

"%nssm:\\=\%" install %serviceName% "%maindir%\\%serviceExe%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

In my original script i had the nssm exe as a variable:

```
%nssm% set %serviceName% AppDirectory "%maindir%"
```

Somehow this confuses the script.

Just use an actual path to `nssm.exe` and it works:

```
.\nssm.exe set %serviceName% AppDirectory "%maindir%"
```

Comment: Sorry, I admit I didn't supply the correct example as I was in a hurry. In my edit I added the actual script I was using before. In that I have replaced the variable `nssm` with the path to the actual executable and it now works.